# Can this plugin gstreamer1.0-libav be used in india?

Tags: plugins, video-player, totem

While playing a video on default player in Ubuntu, I got a error message saying that it needs to install an extra plugin *gstreamer1.0-libav*.  There is a warning besides it saying that the plugin is restricted in some countries. Can this be used in India?
[image: plugin_warning_screenshot]

Comment: Can anyone tell if this can be used in India or if there are any restrictions applicable?

Answer (score 0):

There is no technical problem here, but a legal one. Some countries have illiberal laws called “Digital restrictive management” and software patents, if you country has these laws then it is probably illegal for you to use this software.

Therefore you question is a legal one. You need to find out about local laws.